# Can not SSH into machine from local network when gateway route is added to netplan config

Tags: networking, ssh, network-manager, netplan

Ok, so to SSH into this machine from the local network, I have had to set a route with the default gateway of the IP of the machine, I am sure this is wrong, my current config looks like this

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: no
      routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 10.0.0.125
      dhcp6: yes
      addresses: [10.0.0.125/32]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

I believe my config is supposed to look like

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: no
      routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 10.0.0.1
      dhcp6: yes
      addresses: [10.0.0.125/32]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

but when I use the above config, I can not SSH into the machine from the local network

Any ideas on how I can set a route so that I can SSH into the machine from my local network?

Answer (score 0):

The correct config is

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 10.0.0.1
      dhcp6: yes
      addresses: [10.0.0.125/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

You had declared a /32 netmask for your interface, which means the kernel does not consider any other addresses "local".  Assuming you want 10.0.0.x to be treated as "local", the correct netmask is /24.

You also were declaring both a default route (to 0.0.0.0/0) and a gateway4.  You only need to do one of these.

You do not need to declare dhcp4: no, as this defaults to no.